# Convert web table to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read the following table on this site to a Pandas DataFrame

http://www.scb.se/sv_/Hitta-statistik/Statistik-efter-amne/Priser-och-konsumtion/Konsumentprisindex/Konsumentprisindex-KPI/33772/33779/Konsumentprisindex-KPI/272151/

I have done the following

```
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://www.scb.se/sv_/Hitta-statistik/Statistik-efter-amne/Priser-och-konsumtion/Konsumentprisindex/Konsumentprisindex-KPI/33772/33779/Konsumentprisindex-KPI/272151/'

df = pd.read_html(url,index_col='År')
```

How do I make these values: `"År    Jan Feb Mar Apr Maj Jun Jul Aug Sep Okt Nov Dec Årsmedel"` to column values.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your code returns a list consisting of a single element, when you access this element it returns a df:

```
In [36]:
url = 'http://www.scb.se/sv_/Hitta-statistik/Statistik-efter-amne/Priser-och-konsumtion/Konsumentprisindex/Konsumentprisindex-KPI/33772/33779/Konsumentprisindex-KPI/272151/'
​
df = pd.read_html(url,index_col='År')
df[0]

Out[36]:
        Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    Maj    Jun    Jul    Aug    Sep    Okt  \
År                                                                           
2015  31075  31293  31319  31316  31424  31333  31343  31281  31406  31429   
2014  31139  31270  31268  31389  31405  31470  31367  31335  31385  31402   
2013  31200  31339  31465  31403  31454  31399  31355  31384  31505  31440   
2012  31185  31392  31480  31549  31523  31445  31323  31355  31481  31459   
2011  30615  30802  31011  31144  31202  31128  31113  31123  31341  31342   
2010  29979  30159  30232  30236  30292  30297  30204  30206  30460  30557   
2009  29788  29795  29880  29926  29945  30017  29880  29942  30035  30111   
2008  29409  29528  29808  29967  30099  30245  30211  30198  30508  30556   
2007  28501  28645  28833  28979  28948  28995  28949  28941  29230  29385   
2006  27959  28090  28289  28432  28476  28468  28419  28438  28604  28607   
2005   2779   2792   2798   2802   2803   2804   2794   2799   2819   2824   
2004   2780   2773   2794   2794   2801   2789   2785   2782   2802   2810   
2003   2760   2784   2798   2788   2785   2777   2768   2767   2787   2789   
2002   2688   2694   2718   2729   2736   2732   2723   2724   2745   2754   
2001   2617   2626   2646   2669   2687   2683   2669   2676   2699   2691   
2000   2575   2587   2599   2600   2613   2612   2600   2602   2620   2626   
1999   2562   2563   2573   2579   2583   2587   2576   2576   2594   2597   
1998   2569   2566   2570   2577   2581   2576   2570   2557   2568   2573   
1997   2546   2542   2552   2570   2570   2574   2573   2574   2598   2596   
1996   2556   2558   2570   2576   2573   2563   2557   2545   2560   2559   
1995   2513   2523   2533   2550   2553   2551   2548   2545   2562   2569   
1994   2451   2459   2468   2478   2483   2484   2484   2485   2507   2510   
1993   2410   2416   2427   2437   2431   2423   2419   2423   2445   2452   
1992   2302   2303   2313   2319   2320   2315   2312   2313   2346   2351   
1991   2189   2250   2258   2271   2273   2270   2271   2267   2292   2301   
1990   1990   1999   2054   2052   2064   2062   2082   2096   2120   2134   
1989   1830   1840   1847   1865   1873   1879   1879   1887   1902   1918   
1988   1716   1729   1737   1752   1758   1763   1771   1775   1788   1802   
1987   1644   1644   1647   1651   1652   1649   1669   1678   1694   1701   
1986   1589   1590   1587   1597   1597   1597   1601   1599   1613   1619   
1985   1496   1510   1521   1527   1545   1539   1538   1538   1545   1555   
1984   1394   1389   1409   1418   1428   1424   1428   1439   1448   1455   
1983   1291   1288   1293   1303   1311   1318   1329   1335   1345   1356   
1982   1174   1190   1193   1201   1207   1211   1219   1222   1229   1246   
1981   1072   1093   1098   1105   1112   1116   1126   1135   1143   1150   
1980    953    968    972    979    982    985    993    999   1027   1042   

        Nov    Dec  Årsmedel  
År                            
2015  31375  31421     31335  
2014  31356  31405     31349  
2013  31420  31504     31406  
2012  31382  31461     31420  
2011  31416  31478     31143  
2010  30658  30873     30346  
2009  30103  30169     29966  
2008  30306  29899     30061  
2007  29575  29632     29051  
2006  28643  28643     28422  
2005   2817   2818      2804  
2004   2794   2794      2792  
2003   2783   2786      2781  
2002   2747   2751      2728  
2001   2692   2695      2671  
2000   2627   2625      2607  
1999   2590   2596      2581  
1998   2567   2562      2570  
1997   2592   2591      2573  
1996   2553   2549      2560  
1995   2568   2560      2548  
1994   2508   2504      2485  
1993   2453   2443      2432  
1992   2340   2349      2324  
1991   2311   2308      2272  
1990   2141   2139      2078  
1989   1922   1928      1881  
1988   1805   1809      1767  
1987   1707   1707      1670  
1986   1619   1623      1603  
1985   1565   1571      1538  
1984   1464   1488      1432  
1983   1364   1375      1326  
1982   1256   1259      1217  
1981   1154   1149      1121  
1980   1048   1052      1000
```

The [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html#pandas.read_html) state that `read_html` returns a `list` of dfs